# Will mutex work across multiple instances in .Net

Tags: .net, locking, mutex, multiple-instances

I'm a newbie to this forum and please bear with my first post. I'm working on a .Net application migrated from VB6 which uses multiple instances of same class for multiprocessing. But one file operation in .Net is taking longer time than vb6 and this is causing issue in .Net since listeners are used to monitor it. I'm wondering if mutex could be used to lock this method( that has got file operation) so that no other instance will execute this code. The code is similar to below.

```
Main()
{
FileWriter objA = new FileWriter()
FileWriter objB = new FileWriter() 
...
objA.CreatePDFFile()
objB.CreatePDFFile()
...
}

Class FileWriter
{

bool CreatePDFFile()
{
using ( Mutex mutx = new Mutex( false, @"Global\" + appGuid)
{  
   mutx.WaitOne();
   ....//File operations code over here
   mutx.ReleaseMutex()

}
}
}
```

Please let me know if the above approach will work.

Answer (score 0):

A mutex synchronizes access by virtue of only being held by a single thread at any given time. Your code will prevent multiple instances of `FileWriter.CreatePDFFile()` from executing at the same time.

Because it uses a *named* mutex it will also synchronize access across processes on the system, e.g. all instances of all applications that use the `FileWriter` class.

Your description of the simulation is confusing. The mutex will have no effect if you are only running one process that uses the class, and that process has only a single thread.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just want the code inside mutex block to be executed by only one instance at any point of time. I've worked on multi threading in the past but this is the only time I've come across multiple instances for same class & method. I may be wrong in calling it as multiprocess simulation. I'll test it out tomorrow and will update further on it.

Comment: The only way the code can run concurrently for multiple instances is by having multiple threads. Multiple processes is the poor man's way of running multiple threads. (Okay, there is another way, though it doesn't seem to apply here. You could have an instance method that invokes itself for a different instance, e.g. recursing down a list. In that case there would be no blocking or deadlock because the mutex is owned by the thread is accessing all of the instances.)